# Fail to find an Android device sound file

Tags: internal-storage, audio, alarm, clock, custom-sounds

In the clock app (bedtime tab, sleep sounds) I can choose a device sound `Deep space`.

I would love to use it as my alarm sound.

Every file-exploring app that I have used hasn't found this file.

How can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest extracting the APK of the app from /data/app. Copy it to sdcard.
Rename clock.apk to clock.zip, extract it and starts looking for sound files.
Format will probably be something like deep_space.ogg.
Good luck

Comment: any less intrusive way to rip it?

Comment: It's pretty simple really, only other thing I can think of is recording it.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but I cannot find  /data/data using a few file managers (including Google "files").

Comment: So you need to find the package name of the app you want and then search for thee package name in /data/app/, the APK will be there. I'd recommend using FX file explorer, you can get the APK  directly there is an option in the app to do that.